# Get line and file where object is created in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the line and file where a object is created?
For example.

I know the print PHP error outputs where a error occurred and at which line. Is it possible to use that mechanism?

Sending the file to the object is easy. I can just use `basename(__FILE__)` as an argument. But I would prefer if the object arguments can remain empty. Like this:

**Foo.php**

```
<?php

  class Foo {

    public $line = null;

    public function __construct(){

      $this->line = where_object_is_assigned

    }

  }

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php

  $object = new Foo();
  echo $object->line // Output Index.php line 3

?>
```

Is there a way for the object to access this data without sending it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the function `debug_backtrace();`

```
<?php

  class Foo {

    public $line = null;

    public function __construct(){
      $bt = debug_backtrace();
      $caller = array_shift($bt); // Get first array

      $this->line = $caller["line"];

    }

  }

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php

  $object = new Foo();
  echo $object->line // Output: 3

?>
```

The function must be used in `__construct()` else it won't work.

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: I dont know how it will affect performance - could be worth a lookup if you are going to use it in a larger heavier production enviroment.

Comment: Its finding the current object line number where you have created an instance which is on `line 3`

Comment: We will be running it on a test environment to measure the performance. Thanks!

Comment: just have this run when a debug bool is true. class Foo{ public static debug=false; ...}, or scoped to some context class / global. Then you can pass ?debug=true in the URL and turn on your heavy debug code if the request is coming from a safe computer.

Answer (score 1):

This will output on which line-number the object is created

Class

```
  class Foo {

    public $line = NULL;

    public function __construct($line){

      $this->line = $line;

    }

  }
```

Index.php

```
  <?php
  $object = new Foo(__LINE__); //Will output 1
  echo $object->line;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't want to pass any argument to Foo. Check my answer for a method that avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a large number of predefined constants to any script which it runs. Within this you can simply find the predefined constant named as **LINE**

> `__LINE__` The current line number of the file.

So  you need to simply use the predefined constant within your code like as

```
<?php

  class Foo {

    public $line = __LINE__;

  }

  $object = new Foo();
  echo $object->line;

?>
```

Comment: Am I forced to send it as an argument or is there a workaround? LINE in class Foo will output 5 and __FILE__ will output Foo.php

Comment: If you assign the value of your variable within `__construct` then it'll give you that line

Comment: Ehm, __LINE__ in this case always lives @ line 5. I would set $line in the functions i want to know what line im currently on. And then have a getter so i can always get my line.

Comment: Also he wants the line-number where the object were created, not where in the particular class.